# Stack build error when compiling haskell-servant-cookbook example

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I try to build the project "https://github.com/algas/haskell-servant-cookbook" using stack build, I always get below error on my mac machine. I'm looking for some help to find what I'm missing here

````
--  While building package pcre-light-0.4.0.4 using:
      /Users/808375/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-osx/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/lib --bindir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/bin --datadir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/share --libexecdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/etc --docdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --htmldir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --haddockdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/pcre-light-0.4.0.4 --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 -f-old_base --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1


--  While building package mysql-0.1.7 using:
      /private/var/folders/22/p4q9klbd7l75c680b5hf10mw8_rkx6/T/stack95907/mysql-0.1.7/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1 configure --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/pkgdb --libdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/lib --bindir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/bin --datadir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/share --libexecdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/libexec --sysconfdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/etc --docdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/mysql-0.1.7 --htmldir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/mysql-0.1.7 --haddockdir=/Users/808375/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/de99b86bb99430d571d8ce91b535ceb539abe112ba7d6080374dd59296002fd2/8.6.5/doc/mysql-0.1.7 --dependency=Cabal=Cabal-2.4.1.0-3JC906oWQ73Ah7bYkIcI4J --dependency=base=base-4.12.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.8.2 --dependency=containers=containers-0.6.0.1 -f-developer --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1```
````

Comment: Is there `mysql` client on your mac machine? It could be the fault reason, if no

Comment: Hi Palik, 
I have mysql installed on my mac and when I ran mysql_config --version, it gives 8.0.17..

Comment: Sorry for a foolish attempt to help you. I faced same exception on debian based system, while `libmysqlclient-dev` wasn't installed. Installation of the package solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Setup.hs](https://github.com/paul-rouse/mysql/blob/daaac0047bc98d85ea413fa0fabbd0fb9fb8776e/Setup.hs#L43) of [mysql](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql) package calls `mysql_config`. I guess in your environment it doesn't exist yet.